# Parse hex and ASCII characters into string in Python

Tags: python, hex, ascii, data-conversion

I have a file with line like this : `\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00{` and I want to parse it like this : `04:01:00:00:00:00:00:7b`, where `{` must be converted in hex (`{` = `7b`).

I'm trying to build a little python script, but the tricky part of converting some (not all) characters into hex is hard for me.

Here is my beginnig method:

```py
def hex_parser(line):
    result = ''
    for l in line:
        if len(result):
            result = result + ':'
        if l != '\\' or l != ',' or l != '\n':
            tmp_l = l.encode('utf8').hex()
            if len(tmp_l) == 1:
                tmp_l = '0' + tmp_l
            result = result + tmp_l
    return result
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line will do what you ask:

```
result = ":".join([f"{ord(hex_value):02X}" for hex_value in line if hex_value not in ['\\','\n',',']])
```

This does for every character in the line, skipping those defined in a list:

1. Converts to integer using `ord`. `'\x00' = 0, '{' = 123`
2. Uses string formatting to to convert to a two digit hex number

Lastly it takes the list and join every part together into a string with a `:` between every element

EDIT:

Here is a function that parses lines that include the actual hex representation (`\x00`) in the text file, which results in strings like `\\x00` in python

```
import re

def hex_parser(line):
    hex_values = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(line):
        if re.match("\\\\x[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}",line[i:i+4]):
            hex_values.append(line[i+2:i+4])
            i+= 4
        else:
            hex_values.append(f"{ord(line[i]):02X}")
            i += 1
    skip_values = [f"{ord(c):02X}" for c in ['\\','\n',',']]
    return ":".join([h for h in hex_values if h not in skip_values])
```

Comment: I don't get a thing : when I use your line with a string example like this : `hex_parser("\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00/")` where hex_parser is just a return of your line, it works. But when I open the file, read it, and pass the exact same value stored in a variable, python want to convert every single characters (even the first x in `\x00`. I think when I pass directly the string, python interprets it like a hex string, but with the file it doesn't do the same thing

Comment: Depends on how the file looks like. When you type "\x00" in python, that means its a string of length 1 containing a `null` character. If you have a file containing `\x00` then read that, then it will be a string of length 4 with the characters `\ `, `x`, `0` and `0`

Comment: Your right, in my case the file is a txt file so every hex line is treated like `x` is a character ... Have you any idea to bypass this problem ? (converting the file in hex or something like this)

Comment: How does the text file actually look? Does it have `\x00` or "random" characters like `€eYäþšÈ[È` ?

Comment: It as both : example of a line in the file : `}689}\x03\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06@*0',` where `}689}` is just a timestamp, not a hex value

Comment: Added a function that parses `\x00`-like blocks in the text, hopefully that maybe help you

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the file in binary mode:

```
with open("file.txt", "rb") as f:
    for l in f.readlines(): # reads the file line by line
        print(":".join(["%02x"%ord(c) for c in l])) # go through each character and format it as hex string, put all together with ":" inbetween
```